# Unaccounted-for characters in a C string

Tags: c, string, pointers

I created a pointer of type `char *`, and allocated it, through the `malloc()` function, a memory chunk equal to `size`, which is an `int` variable whose value is determined by the user. Then, using a `while` and a `for` loop, I allocate a single character to all the indexes of the resulting character array. However, when I check the resulting string's length through the `strlen()` function, it always returns a larger value than `size`, by a margin greater than 1 (which might account for the NUL character). This margin appears to be random.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main()
{
    /* your code */
    char *letters, j;
    int size, i = 0, counter = 0;

    scanf("%d", &size);
    if (size < (1024 * 1024)) {
        letters = (char *) malloc(size);
        if (letters != NULL) {
            while (i < size - 1) {
                for (j = 65; j <= 90; j++) {
                    letters[i] = j;
                    i++;
                }
            }
            printf("%lu", strlen(letters));
            free(letters);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Too much memory requested.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
/* I was expecting an output equal to the input, but the output always exceeds
my input by a random value, which is larger than 1. */
```

Comment: You never 0-terminate the array to make it a valid string. And looks like it'll write out of bounds if `size` isn't a multiple of 25...

Comment: Don't do this  `for(j = 65; j <= 90; j++)`, that makes the code unnecessarily harder to read.  `for(j = 'A'; j <= 'Z'; j++)`. The less harcdoded numbers you use, the better. `strlen(letters)` will fail, because you are not creating a proper C-string, it needs to end with `\0`.

Comment: Plus the format for printing `size_t` values like `strlen()` returns is `%zu`, not `%lu`.

Comment: Style suggestion: write your check on the size of `size` as a guard. `if (size >= 1024 * 1024) { printf("Too much memory requested.\n"); return 1; }` and then proceed knowing the input was okay. Alternatively, read in the size and try the allocation. Check the return value from `malloc` to know if it worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing undefined behavior from not null-terminating strings. The mistake may be thinking that `malloc` returns memory that is zero-initialized. It *might* but that's not guaranteed. You could use `calloc` to obtain that result.

You can also clean up your logic a bit by:

- Using guard checks rather than nested conditionals.
- Not casting `malloc`
- Scoping variables as tightly as possible and only declaring them once you need them.

You'll also want to add a check in your inner loop on `i` to ensure there is not out-of-bounds memory access.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    size_t size, i = 0;

    if (scanf("%zu", &size) != 1 || size >= 1024 * 1024) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }
    
    char *letters = malloc(size);
    if (!letters) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (i < size - 1) {
        for (char j = 'A'; i < size - 1 && j <= 'Z'; j++) {
            letters[i] = j;
            i++;
        }
    }

    // Ensure the string is null-terminated.
    letters[i] = '\0';
            
    printf("%zu", strlen(letters));
    free(letters);

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, it seems that your function would just be printing `size - 1` in this case, which can be done without all of the memory allocation and looping.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `letters[i] = 0;` after the `while` loop to terminate the string. Though it sounds like it was getting terminated anyway. In general you cannot depend on `malloc()` initializing the memory it delivers.

Your inner loop *always* adds 26 characters to the string. The resulting length will then be a multiple of 26. It will be larger than the number you entered for most values. It could be one less or equal to what you entered, or as much as 24 more than what you entered. That also has the unfortunate effect of writing beyond the bounds of the memory you allocated. You need to add 25 to `size` in the `malloc()` argument to assure enough memory.